# Postgres - indication for no rows updated

Tags: postgresql

I'm running a simple update query, something like:

```
UPDATE some_table SET columnA = 'value' WHERE columnB = 'other value'
```

There is a way in a Postgres to raise an error or print some message when there are no rows updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the database, this is only possible when doing the update from a stored procedure. In plpgsql:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE some_table SET columnA = 'value' WHERE columnB = 'other value'
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        raise exception 'Nothing updated'; 
    END IF;
END
```

The value is however not logged, but the command is cancelled. If you just want it logged, use `raise warning` instead, and set the postgresql logging to include warnings.

If you use an API to access PostgreSQL, you usually have a function that returns the number of values updated. In Java e.g. there is the Statement class, with the function executeUpdate():

> ```
> public int executeUpdate(String sql)
>                   throws SQLException
> ```
>
> Executes the given SQL statement,
>   which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or
>   DELETE statement or an SQL statement
>   that returns nothing, such as an SQL
>   DDL statement.
>
> **Parameters:** sql - an SQL INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement or an SQL
>   statement that returns nothing
>
> **Returns:** ***either the row count for INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE
>   statements, or 0 for SQL statements
>   that return nothing***
>
> **Throws:** SQLException - if a database access error occurs or the
>   given SQL statement produces a
>   ResultSet object